# How can I add a contextual menu item to all files on mac os x?

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

I want to add a contextual menu item to all files that allows to copy the file in a special path. And if possible, I want to add an icon to the menu item.
I'm working on mac os x.

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy to accomplish. You will work in Automator and create a Service Workflow. ([See info here.](http://www.macosxautomation.com/services/learn/index.html))
Since you tagged "Applescript", I assume you know Applescript. Just use an Applescript action within Automator to get the file path(s) and do what you want with them. You could also use the copy action to copy the files.